# How to use each in this case

Tags: jquery, this, each

i imagine that .each() is solution for this case, where i use classes with prefixes, how to use .each() in this case?

I tried many of ways and did not get success

HTML

```
<div id="huge_it_slideshow_image_container_1" class="huge_it_slideshow_image_container_1">        
<div class="huge_it_slide_container_1">
<div class="huge_it_slide_bg_1">
<ul class="huge_it_slider_1">
<li class="huge_it_slideshow_image_item_1" id="image_id_1_0" style="transition: opacity 1000ms linear; opacity: 0; z-index: 1;">      
<img id="huge_it_slideshow_image_1_0" class="huge_it_slideshow_image_1" src="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/another_world_wallpaper_II___by_night_fate.jpg" alt="Teste" data-image_id="5">

<div class="huge_it_slideshow_title_text_1 none">Garantia de integridade,</div>
<div class="huge_it_slideshow_description_text_1 none">tranquilidade e qualidade dos funcionários  Esse é o nosso principal objetivo!</div>
</li>

<li class="huge_it_slideshow_image_second_item_1" id="image_id_1_1" style="transition: opacity 1000ms linear; opacity: 1; z-index: 2;">      
<a href="http://huge-it.com" target="_blank">
<img id="huge_it_slideshow_image_1_1" class="huge_it_slideshow_image_1" src="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/homerb.jpg" alt="Garantia de integridade," data-image_id="3">
</a>        
<div class="huge_it_slideshow_title_text_1">Garantia de integridade,</div>
<div class="huge_it_slideshow_description_text_1">tranquilidade e qualidade dos funcionários  Esse é o nosso principal objetivo!</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="huge_it_current_image_key_1" value="1">
</div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function(){

      // Change behavior title and description HUGE IT
      var huge_it_title = $( "*[class*='huge_it_slideshow_title_text_']" ).text();
      $( "*[class*='huge_it_slideshow_description_text_']" ).prepend( "<span style='font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase;'>" + huge_it_title + "</span><br>" );

    });
```

Comment: What is your expected behaviour? You don't explain it.

Comment: @A.Wolff get value of var huge_it_title and apply this value in $( "*[class*='huge_it_slideshow_description_text_']" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chain `.each()` to `huge_it_title`, where `this` within callback will be current `DOM` element; within callback you can reference current element text using `.textContent`

```
var huge_it_title = $("*[class*='huge_it_slideshow_title_text_']");
$("*[class*='huge_it_slideshow_description_text_']")
.each(function(index, el) {
  $(this)
  .prepend("<span style='font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase;'>" 
           + huge_it_title[index].this.textContent + "</span><br>")
});
```

You can alternatively use `.prepend(function)` or `.html(function)`

```js
$(function() {
  var huge_it_title = $("*[class*='huge_it_slideshow_title_text_']");
  $("*[class*='huge_it_slideshow_description_text_']")
  .prepend(function(index, html) {
      return "<span style='font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase;'>" 
             + huge_it_title[index].textContent 
             + "</span><br>" + html
    }).first().css("opacity", 1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="huge_it_slideshow_image_container_1" class="huge_it_slideshow_image_container_1">
  <div class="huge_it_slide_container_1">
    <div class="huge_it_slide_bg_1">
      <ul class="huge_it_slider_1">
        <li class="huge_it_slideshow_image_item_1" id="image_id_1_0" style="style=""transition: opacity 1000ms linear; opacity: 0; z-index: 1;">
          <img id="huge_it_slideshow_image_1_0" class="huge_it_slideshow_image_1" src="" alt="Teste" data-image_id="5">

          <div class="huge_it_slideshow_title_text_1 none">Garantia de integridade,</div>
          <div class="huge_it_slideshow_description_text_1 none">tranquilidade e qualidade dos funcionários Esse é o nosso principal objetivo!</div>
        </li>

        <li class="huge_it_slideshow_image_second_item_1" id="image_id_1_1" style="transition: opacity 1000ms linear; opacity: 1; z-index: 2;">
          <a href="http://huge-it.com" target="_blank">
            <img id="huge_it_slideshow_image_1_1" class="huge_it_slideshow_image_1" src="" alt="Garantia de integridade," data-image_id="3">
          </a>
          <div class="huge_it_slideshow_title_text_1">Garantia de integridade,</div>
          <div class="huge_it_slideshow_description_text_1">tranquilidade e qualidade dos funcionários Esse é o nosso principal objetivo!</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="huge_it_current_image_key_1" value="1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP wants to prepend content to different elements. The question isn't clear enough imho

Comment: @A.Wolff Did not initially notice different selectors. See updated post

Comment: does not return any value

Comment: @PabloCampina _"does not return any value"_ Can you include `html` at Question? Create stacksnippets or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is expected result?

Comment: @PabloCampina Returns expected result at stacksnippet. See updated post

Comment: here Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined

Comment: Do `"*[class*='huge_it_slideshow_title_text_']"` and `"*[class*='huge_it_slideshow_description_text_']"` have the same `.length` ? Are there more of one collection of elements than the other? Can you reproduce the error at jsfiddle?

Comment: your alternative script works, but one time for index 0, after slide change don't work anymore

Comment: What do you mean by "after slide change"?

Comment: @guest271314 first way works too, same way if remove .this huge_it_title[index].textContent

Comment: @guest271314 my <ul> have 2 <li> right? when first <li> changes for second <li> with same class name, the values don't work anymore, understand?

Comment: The `html` is being set. You have the `opacity` of the first `li` set to `0` at `style="transition: opacity 1000ms linear; opacity: 0; z-index: 1;"`. See updated post

Comment: @guest271314 got it, it's possible change behavior in script?

Comment: @guest271314 see my output `debug console.log( 'index: ' + index + ' el:' + el);` `console.log( huge_it_title[index] );` see GIF https://www.dropbox.com/s/orehkap5q8gam8g/2016-10-20%2012.05.15.gif?dl=0

Comment: @PabloCampina Does `javascript` at stacksnippets return expected result?

Comment: @guest271314 sorry, i do not understand

Comment: @PabloCampina Does the `html`, and `javascript` at stacksnippets resolve Question?

Comment: @guest271314 `html` i'm not control, i receive via plugin wordpress, i tried with `css` but don't work, se the gif https://www.dropbox.com/s/ns7gnmg6rcswlgs/2016-10-21%2011.26.56.gif?dl=0

Comment: @guest271314 `huge_it_slideshow_title_text_*` appear one time only, and the first slide too

Comment: @PabloCampina _"`huge_it_slideshow_title_text_*` appear one time only, and the first slide too"_ ? There are two elements which have `className` which contains `huge_it_slideshow_title_text_` at `html` at Question. The original Question is about each, not a slideshow.

Comment: @guest271314 i'm change the plugin.. thanks for help